# Primefaces datatable update cell value from another entity class only after server restart

Tags: jsf, jpa, primefaces, jsf-2, datatable

I am having a problem with showing cell value using primefaces datatable. Originally table was displaying fields from only one entity class (Document). I needed to add additional field from another class (DocData). I managed to do that by adding the transient field "oib" into the Document class (field name oib is stored in the third class DocTypeField).

The problem now is that after inserting new row only fields from Document class are displayed. Refresh page also doesn't help. Only thing that will result with displaying new data (oib) is server restart.

This is my database model:

[image: databasemodel]

This is Document class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ACQ_DOCUMENT")
@NamedQuery(name="Document.findAll", query="SELECT a FROM Document a")
@NoArgsConstructor
@ViewScoped
public @Data class Document implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 2611447987879527170L;

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "DocumentSEQ",sequenceName = "ACQ_DOCUMENT_SEQ",allocationSize=1)    
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY,generator = "DocumentSEQ" )  
@Column(name="DOCUMENT_ID")
private Integer id;

@Column(name="DOCUMENT_FIRST_NAME")
private String firstName;

@Column(name="DOCUMENT_LAST_NAME")
private String lastName;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="DOCUMENT_DOC_TYPE_ID")
private DocType docType;

@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="DATA_DOCUMENT_ID")
private List<DocData> docData;  

@Transient
private String oib;

public String getOib() {
    if (oib == null) {
        for(DocData dd : docData) {
            if(dd.getDocTypeField().getName().equals("oib") && (dd.getDocument().getId().equals(id))) {
                oib =  dd.getStringValue();             
            }
        }
    }       
    return oib;
}

public void setOib(String oib){     
    this.oib = oib;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.getClass().getName() + "[id=" + id + "]";
}
}
```

This is DocTypeField class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ACQ_DOC_TYPE_FIELD")
@NamedQuery(name="DocTypeField.findAll", query="SELECT a FROM DocTypeField a")
@NoArgsConstructor
public @Data class DocTypeField implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 2109749245241103862L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="ACQ_DOC_TYPE_FIELD_SEQ")
@Column(name="FIELD_ID")
private Integer id;

@Column(name="FIELD_NAME")
private String name;

@Column(name="field_type")
private String type;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to AcqDocType
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="FIELD_DOC_TYPE_ID")
private DocType docType;

@Column(name="field_active")
private Boolean active;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.getClass().getName() + "[id=" + id + "]";
}
}
```

This is DocData class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ACQ_DOC_DATA")
@NamedQuery(name="DocData.findAll", query="SELECT a FROM DocData a")
@NoArgsConstructor
public @Data class DocData implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 915219051205073130L;

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "DocDataSEQ",sequenceName = "ACQ_DOC_DATA_SEQ",allocationSize=1)    
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY,generator = "DocDataSEQ" )  
@Column(name="DATA_ID")
private Integer id;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="DATA_DATE_VALUE")
private Date dateValue;

@Column(name="DATA_DECIMAL_VALUE")
private BigDecimal decimalValue;

@Column(name="DATA_INT_VALUE")
private Integer intValue;

@Column(name="DATA_STRING_VALUE")
private String stringValue;

@Lob
@Column(name="DATA_TEXT_VALUE")
private String textValue;

@Column(name="DATA_TIMESTAMP_VALUE")
private Timestamp timestampValue;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to AcqBlobValue
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="DATA_BLOB_VALUE_ID")
private BlobValue blobValue;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to AcqDocTypeField
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="DATA_DOC_TYPE_FIELD_ID")
private DocTypeField docTypeField;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to AcqDocument
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="DATA_DOCUMENT_ID")
private Document document;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.getClass().getName() + "[id=" + id + "]";
}
}
```

And finally this is datatable definition:

```
<p:dataTable lazy="true" id="documents" var="item" value="#{documentManager.lazyModel}"  selection="#{documentManager.formObject}"
        selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{item.id}" sortBy="#{item.id}" sortMode="single"
        paginator="true" rows="15" paginatorPosition="bottom"  styleClass="alignTop">

        <p:ajax event="rowSelect"  listener="#{documentManager.onRowSelect}" />

        <f:facet name="header">#{e['adrDocument']}</f:facet>
        <p:column width="10%" sortBy="#{item.id}">
            <f:facet name="header">#{e['adrDocument.id']}</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.id}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column width="10%" sortBy="#{item.firstName}">
            <f:facet name="header">#{e['adrDocument.firstName']}</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.firstName}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column width="10%" sortBy="#{item.lastName}">
            <f:facet name="header">#{e['adrDocument.lastName']}</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.lastName}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column width="10%" sortBy="#{item.docType.descr}">
            <f:facet name="header">#{e['adrDocument.tipDokumenta']}</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.docType.descr}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column width="10%" sortBy="#{item.oib}">
            <f:facet name="header">#{e['adrDocument.oib']}</f:facet> 
            <h:outputText value="#{item.oib}" />                
        </p:column>

     <p:confirmDialog global="true" width="250">  
        <p:commandButton value="#{m['ui.edit.confirm.yes']}" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check"/>  
        <p:commandButton value="#{m['ui.edit.confirm.no']}" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close"/>       
    </p:confirmDialog> 

</p:dataTable>
```

So, item.oib isn't properly displayed. I also tried removing lazyloading, different oib fetching and so on... Have no more ideas.

Comment: How is your documentManager scoped?

Comment: my documentManager is ViewScoped